# DateTime calender in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetimepicker

The date time displays as 07/10/2011 01:29:20 I want to display only 07/10/2011 01:29 how can I do that.

```
     DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
        txt_ExpiresBy.Text = Convert.ToString(now);
```

And I have this datetime calendar which I assign it to a text box, I have to assign this calendar to 3 text box, How can I do it. Should I use three Javascript with different name or can I do with this below?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('.datePicker').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>

<asp:TextBox ID="forDatePicker" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt_ExpiresBy.Text = expirestime.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
```

The [Datetime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method is pretty flexible or you can use one of the other methods such as `ToShortDateString()`.

See the MSDN docs for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

---

Using the class name to assign the `datetimepicker` to multiple textboxes should work just fine.

Comment: @John - No problem. I updated the answer to specifically address your required format.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method.

```
DateTime expirestime = expirestime.AddHours(12);
txt_ExpiresBy.Text = expirestime.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

with overload ToString Method

this.txt_ExpiresBy.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy" + " " + "hh:mm");

Regards